# Modifying ComboBox SelectedIndex Without Triggering Event in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

My C# application has a `comboBox` with a `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  Usually, I want this event to fire, but but sometimes I need the event to not fire.  My `comboBox` is an MRU file list.  If a file in the list is found to not exist, the item is removed from the `comboBox`, and the `comboBox` `SelectedIndex` is set to zero.  However, setting the `comboBox` `SelectedIndex` to zero causes the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to fire, which in this case is problematic because it causes some UIF code to be run in the event handler.  Is there a graceful way to disable/enable events for C# form controls?  Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Start the eventhandler method with

```
ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
if (combo.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    return;
}
```

If you're issue is with a different eventhandler you could remove the eventhandler's event registration first.

```
combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= EventHandler<SelectedIndexChangedEventArgs> SomeEventHandler;
combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
combo.SelectedIndexChanged += EventHandler<SelectedIndexChangedEventArgs> SomeEventHandler;
```

Comment: Is this still the broadly accepted way to prevent the event? [by removing and then re-adding after the 'triggering' action] Just seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 13):

I have encountered this many times over the years.  My solution is to have a class level variable called _noise and if I know I am about to change the index of combo or any other similiar control that fires when the selected index changes, I do the following in code.

```
private bool _noise;
```

Here is the code for the control event handler

```
private void cbTest_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (_noise) return;

   // process the events code

   ...

}
```

Then when I know I am going to change the index, I do the following:

```
_noise = true; // cause the handler to ignore the noise...


cbTest.Index = value;


_noise = false;  // let the event process again
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised there isn't a better way of doing this, but this is the way I do it. I actually use the `Tag` field of most controls so I don't have to subclass the control. And I use `true`/`null` as the values, since `null` is the default.

Of course, if you are actually using `Tag`, you'll need to do it differently...

In handler:

```
 private void control_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (control.Tag != null ) return;

    // process the events code

    ...

 }
```

In main code

```
 try 
 {
    control.Tag = true;
    // set the control property
    control.Value = xxx;
or
    control.Index = xxx; 
or
    control.Checked = xxx;
    ...
 }
 finally 
 {
    control.Tag = null;
 }
```

Comment: I like this solution more than a class scoped variable as this value is directly tied to the control in question making it a more robust solution considering if you had to do similar things with different controls (or even the same one) in multiple event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way!

```
combo_box = QComboBox() # your combobox
combo_box.blockSignals(True)
combo_box.setCurrentIndex(self, ix)
combo_box.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: This does seem good.  Can you add a little explanation of what this does better or what it is doing?  For people who don't understand "blockSignals."

Answer (score 1):

One (fairly ugly) way would be to set a flag in the code that deletes the entry and then check that in the `SelectedIndexChanged` handler:

```
if (!deletedEntry)
{
    // Do stuff
}
deletedEntry = false;
```

A better way might be to remove your `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler at the start of the delete method and reinstate it at the end. This way you code won't know the index has changed.