# StackOverflowException occurred in mscorlib.dll with list<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

So, im getting the StackOverflowException occurred in mscorlib.dll stuff when I try to load a combobox with data ( a list filled with data from a database). I use this on my form constructor:

dbATMT is my entity framework database;

```
List<Team> teams = (from t in dbATMT.TeamSet
                          select t).ToList<Team>();

combobox1.Items.AddRange(teams.ToArray());
combobox2.Items.AddRange(teams.ToArray());
```

Then I have this, to avoid that my comboboxs have the same value selected:

```
private void FillList()
    {
        List<Team> teams = (from t in dbATMT.TeamSet
                              select t).ToList<Team>();`(I get my error here)`

        Team teamSelected= (Team)combobox1.SelectedItem;

        List<Team> teams2 = new List<Team>(teams.Count);

        foreach (Team tin equipas)
        {
            teams2.Add(equipa);
        }

        teams2.Remove(teamSelected);

        combobox2.Items.Clear();
        combobox2.Items.AddRange(teams2.ToArray());
        combobox2.SelectedItem = teams2.ToArray()[0];

    }
```

Finally, I call the FillList() on the combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged and the combobox2_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Read the stack trace.

Comment: How many records in that table?

Comment: Maybe you are missing the `in`

Comment: Show the stack trace of the Exception. I am willing to bet its something in the constructor of `Team` based purely on your comment of where you get the Exception.

Comment: @SLaks what am I looking for in the stack trace ? Infinite loop ?

Comment: @Andez 3 records, I have 3 teams.

Comment: @Hackerman sorry was my bad copy-pasting, already edited.

Comment: @Igor this ? make sure you don't have an infinite loop or infinite recursion. sorry, Im not very used to debuggin tools on vs yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of of `FillList` changes the selected index. `FillList` is called when the selected index changes. Hence, an infinite loop that runs until you run out of stack space (the StackOverflowException).

Suggested solutions in a similar question [Modifying ComboBox SelectedIndex Without Triggering Event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356518/modifying-combobox-selectedindex-without-triggering-event-in-c-sharp)

Comment: the thing is that im using the same logic in other forms and Is working just fine...