# C# Listboxes using selectedvaluechanged

Tags: c#, winforms

I usually figure things out but this has me beat.

I have an array of listboxes on a form and a submit button.  The user can pick items from any listbox then click the submit button to choose the confirm the item, but what needs to happen is that if they select something from listbox 1 then change their mind and select something from listbox 2, the item selected in listbox 1 should become unselected.

I can code that in to the eventhandlers but the problem is as soon as I change a value in another listbox programatically it fires another event.  I can't seem to logic my way out of it.

Any ideas would be great otherwise I guess I will just have to put multiple submit buttons.

EDIT:

I figured out what I think is quite an obvious and simple solution in the end. I made use of the focused property to distinguish whether the user or the program was making changes.  Works for both mouse and keyboard selections.

Thanks for the suggestions...

```
 for (int i = 0; i < treatments.Length; i = i + 1)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(ListBoxes[i]);
            this.Controls.Add(Labels[i]);
            this.Controls.Add(Spinners[i]);

            Labels[i].Top = vPosition - 20;
            Labels[i].Left = hPosition;
            Labels[i].Width = 600;

            ListBoxes[i].Left = hPosition;
            ListBoxes[i].Top = vPosition;
            ListBoxes[i].Width = 600;

            Spinners[i].Top = vPosition + ListBoxes[i].Height;
            Spinners[i].Left = hPosition + ListBoxes[i].Width - 60;
            Spinners[i].Width = 40;
            for (int d = 25; d > 0; d = d - 1) { Spinners[i].Items.Add((d).ToString()); }
            Spinners[i].SelectedIndex = 24;



            //EVENT HANDLER CODE that is executed if any selectetindexchange in any LIstbox in array
            ListBoxes[i].SelectedIndexChanged   += (sender, e) =>
                {


                    for (int s = 0; s < i; s = s + 1)

                    {
                        //FIND WHICH LBs[s] IS THE SENDING LISTBOX 
                        if (ListBoxes[s] == sender && ListBoxes[s].Focused == true)
                        {
                            string msg = "sender is ListBox " + s.ToString() + "\nFocus is" + ListBoxes[s].Focused.ToString();
                           // MessageBox.Show(msg);
                        }
                        else if(ListBoxes[s].Focused==false)
                        {
                            ListBoxes[s].SelectedIndex = -1;
                        }                        


                    }


                }; //end of event handler

}
```

Comment: Is a Winforms, Webforms or MVC project?

Comment: You could always use a flag.

Comment: This question is similar, and the answer may be applicable as far as the general strategy: [Modifying combobox SelectedIndex without triggering event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356518/modifying-combobox-selectedindex-without-triggering-event-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @kblok its a Windows Forms

Comment: Add the items as a class, add an id property to it to track which listbox is selected. Then point all listboxes to the same event handler, and by checking the id you know which one was selected. You can cycle through all listboxes, find out if more than two is selected, remove the selectedvaluechanged event, deselect if not the last one selected, and add back the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I generally solve this kind of problem with a flag that lets me know that I am changing things, so my event handlers can check the flag and not take action in that case.

```
private int codeChangingCount = 0;
private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    codeChangingCount++;
    try {
        combobox2.SelectedIndex = someNewValue;
    } finally {
        codeChangingCount--;
    }
}

private void combobox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (codeChangingCount == 0) {
        //I know this is changing because of the user did something, not my code above
    }
}
```

You can do this with a simple `bool` instead of an `int`, but I like the counter approach so that I can keep incrementing `codeChangingCount` in nested calls and not accidentally reset it.  In my production code, I have a class dedicated to this kind of flagging, and it (mis)uses IDisposable to decrement, so I can just wrap my calls in a `using` block, but the above snippet is simpler for illustration.

Comment: I did try this approach but I couldn't get it to work with the way I was using loops and one eventhandler for many listboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Focused ListBox == ListBox2 and SelectedIndex > -1 then deselect Index[0]

```
if (ListBoxes[s] == sender && ListBoxes[s].Focused == true)
    {
      if(s == 1 && ListBoxes[s].SelectedIndex > -1) //assuming 1 is listbox2
        {
          ListBoxes[0].SelectedIndex = -1; // Deselect ListBox1
        }
      string msg = "sender is ListBox " + s.ToString() + "\nFocus is" + ListBoxes[s].Focused.ToString();
    }
```